# Opening repo in Atom via Terminal

Tags: github, atom-editor

Is there a command to open a cloned repo/directory in Atom via Terminal? Basically, the same function as "Open in Atom" in the GitHub app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're specifically asking for a cloned repository, since it's no  different from a normal directory:

```
# Open current directory
atom .

# Open specific directory
atom /path/to/any/directory/under/the/sun
```

If you want to add a folder to an already open Atom session, you can use `atom -a <dir>`. See `atom --help` for more options.

Comment: Definitely–I was just relating it to my scenario. Simple enough. Thanks!